# Position & Wrap a Plane along Mesh in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to deform a plane along the normals of a separate mesh, my goal is to be able to move and wrap the plane around the mesh basically like a shrinkwrap modifier - but using number sliders to control the position instead (kind of like a texture along a UVmap).

I think I've got the shrinkwrap mostly solved but the issue I'm running into is how to position it in a custom way so I can control exactly where I want it to be on the mesh - So far I've tried plugging in a vector math node into the offset but it doesn't seem to work, anyone have any ideas on how to control the position?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]